# Load Ajax Tab via Selectbox

Tags: jquery, tabs

I have this very helpful jquery script from http://www.ajaxblender.com/howto-create-custom-jquery-tabs.html that loads content via ajax into a target div. As you can see. it was written to work with  tags containg an href attribute. Now I'd like to expand the functionality a bit and allow a page to be loaded onto the target div when the appropriate option is selected in the dropdown menu. Though I get most of the code, I'm very new to javascript.

**Here's the script**

```
var containerId = '#tabs-container';
var tabsId = '#tabs';

$(document).ready(function(){
    // Preload tab on page load
    if($(tabsId + ' li.current a').length > 0){
        loadTab($(tabsId + ' li.current a'));
    }

    $(tabsId + ' a').click(function(){
        if($(this).parent().hasClass('current')){ return false; }

        $(tabsId + ' li.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).parent().addClass('current');

        loadTab($(this));       
        return false;
    });
});

function loadTab(tabObj){
    if(!tabObj || !tabObj.length){ return; }
    $(containerId).addClass('loading');
    $(containerId).fadeOut('fast');

    $(containerId).load(tabObj.attr('href'), function(){
        $(containerId).removeClass('loading');
        $(containerId).fadeIn('fast');
    });
}
```

**The Html**

```
    <ul class="ajaxtabs" id="tabs">
        <li class="current"><a href="./music-list.html">Videos</a></li>
        <li><a href="./tab-2.html">Audio</a></li>
        <li class="third-child"><a href="./tab-3.html">Texte</a></li>
        <li>
            <form id="vod_select_nav">
              <select id="standard-dropdown" name="standard-dropdown" class="bigbox" onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_top')">
                <option value="index.php?id=48/#" class="test-class-1">NAVIGUER PAR SERIES &amp; EPISODES</option>
                <option value="./tab-2.html">Past. Ghislain Lukunku, Rév. Jacques Maluma &mdash; Alume La Lampe</option>
            <option value="index.php?id=91">Past. Ghislain Lukunku, Rév. Jacques Maluma &mdash; State Of The Church</option>
            <option value="index.php?id=97">Past. Ghislain Lukunku, Rév. Jacques Maluma &mdash; Non Le Feu Ne S'eteindra&#8230;</option>
              </select>
            </form> 
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="ajaxtabs-container" id="tabs-container">
        Loading. Please Wait...
    </div>
```

The html contains the select box used to navigate to different files without ajax

I know that the solution will depend on modifying this part and calling the function inline from the selectbox

```
$(containerId).load(tabObj.attr('href'), function(){
    $(containerId).removeClass('loading');
    $(containerId).fadeIn('fast');
});
```

Per the jquery API @ http://api.jquery.com/attr/ I know I could do something like:

```
$(containerId).load(tabObj.attr('onchange'), function(){
    $(containerId).removeClass('loading');
    $(containerId).fadeIn('fast');
});
```

But I know it's wrong since since the only thing changing here is the attribute.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

instead of `$(tabsId + ' a').click()`, bind your dropdown's `change` event. You will get the dropdown item as an argument and you can read its value and navigate to the desired page.

This will give you the value associated with the selected item

```
$('#standard-dropdown').change(function (item) {
    alert($('#standard-dropdown').val());

});
```

Comment: Thx for the follow-up. I'm not quite following man, How would I do that exactly?